# Adding multiple values to a key in Ruby as well as delete just one value associated

Tags: ruby, hash

I want  to add values and delete values to the hash like below

```
h= {:a =>[ 1,3, 4],
    :b =>[ 3, 6],
    :c =>[ 4, 8, 87]
   }
```

and how do I delete just one value pertaining to a key?
remove c, 87

```
h= {:a =>[ 1,3, 4],
    :b =>[ 3, 6],
    :c =>[ 4, 8]
   }
```

Can I do this in ruby? I am new to ruby, Can someone help me out?

Comment: Those are not valid ruby objects. Maybe you meant `{:a => [1,3,4]}`? If so then `h[:c].delete_at(h[:c].index(87))` would work.

Comment: Or even `h[:c].delete(87)` depending on how you want to handle potential duplicate values in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am getting this Exception: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass, NoMethodError for both the delete ways

Comment: _"want to add and delete like this"_ – what's being added, what's getting deleted? Also, please fix your example code.

Comment: Holger's code should work with you.  It sounds like you just typed the wrong key or something.  Keep in mind that if you write `h[:c].delete(87)` you probably make sure that `h[:c]` actually exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use a Nil Guard

You need to guard against missing keys and values in your Hash. There are a number of ways to do this, but on any recent Ruby the `&.` operator ensures that a method doesn't raise an exception if called on nil. The following works fine:

```rb
h = {
  a: [1, 3, 4],
  b: [3, 6],
  c: [4, 8, 87]
}

h[:c]&.delete 87; h
#=> {:a=>[1, 3, 4], :b=>[3, 6], :c=>[4, 8]}

h[:x]&.delete 101; h
#=> {:a=>[1, 3, 4], :b=>[3, 6], :c=>[4, 8]}
```

Comment: Thanks, Todd! I checked if the key and value exist before deleting. This is such a better way to do that.